# FFT with offlineAudioContext

Tags: javascript, fft, web-audio-api

I'm trying to do frequency analysis of an audio file, but I want it to happen without playing. I found there was a [`offlineAudioContext`](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/specification.html#OfflineAudioContext-section), which is probably what I need here.

Complete code in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3bfVU/4/)

The Web Audio API is a bit of unexplored territory for me and I'm not completely sure what I'm doing, a lot of the tutorials are focused on realtime audio and that's exactly what I want to prevent.

Inside `context.oncomplete`, I managed to get some accurate looking rendered audiobuffer data. When getting data from the fft, I seem to be getting a very small set of data, which I'm guessing it's just the data from the last sample. I'd rather have this data for every x ms of the audio file that I'm loading. I would love to get some ideas on how to get this format of the data?

Basically what I'm expecting is something like:

```
[
  // array with frequency data for every (nth) frequency band for 1st sample,
  // array with frequency data for every (nth) frequency band for 2nd sample,
  // array with frequency data for every (nth) frequency band for 3rd sample,
  …
]
```

Comment: Please check my answer and mark it as accepted: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57744228/236062

Comment: @Zibri It looks like it might be the right solution, but kind of abandoned this project shortly after the question was posted, so I don't really have the means or energy to verify, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set fftSize on your `AnalyserNode`, you'll get `(fftSize / 2)` number of bins. So that's why you're seeing a lot less data than you expect.

Essentially what's happening is that `getByteFrequencyData` is only looking at the first 128 samples of your rendered buffer, and the rest simply get ignored.

Instead, you might want to try using a `ScriptProcessorNode` with a `bufferSize` equal to your `fftSize`. Then, in the `ScriptProcessorNode`'s `onaudioprocess` event handler, you can grab the buffer and get its FFT. Something like this:

```
var processor = context.createScriptProcessor(fftSize, 1, 1);
source.connect(processor);

processor.onaudioprocess = function( e ) {
  var input = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0),
      data = new Uint8Array(fftSamples);
  fft.getByteFrequencyData(data);
  // do whatever you want with `data`
}
```

Comment: I can't get the onaudioprocess to actually fire, but from what I can tell it's because the audioContext isn't initialised properly. When I use `new webkitAudioContext()` the event fires as expected, but no luck with `webkitOfflineAudioContext`. Seems that one requires some parameters, but even with 1 channel, a super high length and samplerate of 44100 it doesn't seem to do anything. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post a jsFiddle of what you've got so far?

Comment: Oh, man. You're *sooo* close! Just add `context.startRendering()` to the end of that `processBuffer` function and your `onaudioprocess` handler will start working.

Comment: Aw yeah. That looks more like it. Still not exactly working as expected. But I'll dive in it some more. Consider this one answered :)

Comment: Do you happen to know what to set the length parameter to? I'm not sure what value they're expecting and how to get it when I load in an mp3 or something. Any ideas?

Comment: It would basically just be `processBuffer.length` -- or the length of whatever `AudioBuffer` you want to render. The trick here is that you'll probably need an `AudioContext` and an `OfflineAudioContext`. Use the `AudioContext` for `decodeAudioData` so you can get the buffer length, and *then* you can create your offline context to create your `BufferSourceNode` and `ScriptProcessorNode` and do the rendering.

Comment: @Marco did you make it work? im trying to do the same and spent already so much time trying to find solution but got nothing working still..

Comment: @okram I don't think so, but I kind of left this project behind a long time ago ;)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that buffer is a float32array containing a one channel sound,
here is a nice code for offline analysis I wrote.

The function passed to callback will be executed at every step of the analysis.
The function passed to onend will be called at the end of the process.

```
function callback(data) {
    callback.count = callback.count || 0;
    console.log(callback.count++, data);
}
fftAnalyser = function(buff, sampleRate, fftSize, callback, onend) {

    // by Zibri (2019)
    var frequencies = [1000,1200,1400,1600]; //for example
    var frequencyBinValue = (f)=>{
        const hzPerBin = (ctx.sampleRate) / (2 * analyser.frequencyBinCount);
        const index = parseInt((f + hzPerBin / 2) / hzPerBin);
        return data[index]+1;
    }
    ctx = new OfflineAudioContext(1,buff.length,sampleRate);
    ctx.sampleRate = sampleRate;
    ctx.destination.channelCount = 1;

    processor = ctx.createScriptProcessor(1024, 1, 1);
    processor.connect(ctx.destination);

    analyser = ctx.createAnalyser();
    analyser.fftSize = fftSize;
    analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = 0.0;

    //analyser.minDecibels = -60;
    //analyser.maxDecibels = -20;

    source = ctx.createBufferSource();
    source.connect(analyser);

    processor.onaudioprocess = function(e) {
        data = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
        analyser.getByteFrequencyData(data);
        state = frequencies.map(frequencyBinValue.bind(this))
        if ("function" == typeof callback)
            onend();
        callback(state);
    }

    analyser.connect(processor);

    var sbuffer = ctx.createBuffer(1, buff.length, ctx.sampleRate);
    sbuffer.getChannelData(0).set(buff);
    source.buffer = sbuffer;

    source.onended = function(e) {
        console.log("Analysys ended.");
        if ("function" == typeof onend)
            onend();
    }

    console.log("Start Analysis.");

    source.start(0);
    ctx.startRendering();
}
```

Comment: The question might be off topic but... Would it be possible to get the frequency data / frequencyBinCount for a given time? I would like to draw a waveform for the frequency data of a given time when the user seeks through an audio file. Without the audio being played.

Comment: @frizurd sure.. just set the time before the source.start

Comment: a full demo, with a short sound, would be nice :)